# Searching in a specific dpkg for a single file?

Tags: dpkg

Is there a `dpkg` or `dpkg-query` command that search within a specific dpkg file installed on the system? For instance, if I want to find all `pl_PL.aff` provided by the `hunspell-pl` package, can I run that without using grep?

Answer (score 1):

How to determine which package provides a particular file:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/hunspell/en_US.aff
hunspell-en-us: /usr/share/hunspell/en_US.aff   # The package is: hunspell-en-us
```

How to list all the files provided by a package:

```
$ dpkg -L hunspell-en-us 
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/hunspell
/usr/share/hunspell/en_US.aff
/usr/share/hunspell/en_US.dic
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/hunspell-en-us
/usr/share/doc/hunspell-en-us/README.txt
/usr/share/doc/hunspell-en-us/copyright
/usr/share/doc/hunspell-en-us/changelog.Debian.gz
```

dpkg does not include any filter - you must use grep, sed, awk, etc:

```
$ dpkg -L hunspell-en-us | grep aff
/usr/share/hunspell/en_US.aff
```